# How to Stop Yeoman AngularJS Giving Errors Even though Karma Installed Globally

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I'm trying to start a Yeoman AngularJS project and I receive the following errors at the end of the project install. I have installed all of these modules via npm install -g karma and npm install -g phantomjs. Why am I still seeing these errors even though I globally installed karma and phantomjs?

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jasmine-core@*
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY karma@^0.13.0 || >= 0.14.0-rc.0
├── karma-jasmine@0.3.6
├─┬ karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.3
│ └── lodash@3.10.1
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY phantomjs@>=1.9

npm WARN karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.3 requires a peer of karma@>=0.9 but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.3 requires a peer of phantomjs@>=1.9 but none was installed.
npm WARN karma-jasmine@0.3.6 requires a peer of jasmine-core@* but none was installed.
npm WARN grunt-karma@0.12.1 requires a peer of karma@^0.13.0 || >= 0.14.0-rc.0 but none was installed.
```